# using appendChild to currently focused element

Tags: javascript

consider this code:

```js
console.log('New node')
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.appendChild(document.createTextNode("+"));
    document.getElementById("elem").appendChild(node);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
       <body>
          <div id="elem">+</div>
           </body>
    </html>
```

So this currently adds `"+"` as the text of a new div.

Say I want to add another child div with the text `">"` to whatever div the user viewing index.html is currently **focused on**, considering the option he selected a div that was dynamically created, how may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set tab index on a div for it to be focusable, but then you can listen for the focus event and store the last focused element. You need to store your current item manually instead of relying on `document.activeElement` for getting the last focused element, since that would get changed to the button you are clicking.

```js
const appendbtn = document.querySelector('#appendit');
const addbtn = document.querySelector('#addbox');
let activeElement = null;
let counter = 0;
appendbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (activeElement) {
    const node = document.createElement('span');
    node.textContent = '>';
    activeElement.appendChild(node);
  }
});
addbtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const text = document.createElement('span');
  text.textContent = 'Box ' + (counter++);
  
  const box = document.createElement('div');
  box.tabIndex = 0;
  box.classList.add('box');
  box.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    if (activeElement) {
      activeElement.classList.remove('selected');
    }
    activeElement = box;
    activeElement.classList.add('selected');
  });
  box.appendChild(text);

  const container = document.querySelector('.boxes');
  container.appendChild(box);
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.box.selected {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
</div>
<button id="addbox">
  Add box
</button>
<button id="appendit">
  Append chevron
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help.

I don't want to depend on clicks, but to any element that was moved over (say with a tab, or if it was just created)

Comment: It doesn't have to be on click, you can set `activeElement` to whatever you like, from whichever event you want?

Comment: Then my bad, I don't understand the code. also, the snippet doesn't run correctly

Comment: also, this works only on active clicks, not ON FOCUS (e.g. - press TAB and the element isn't activeElement at the moment, but is onfocus)

Comment: Well, you can listen for the focus event on any item you wish, you can probably hook up that to your custom element and set the activeElement to the element that got focused. That's why I mentioned that you can set it in another event, since clicked might not be suited for *your* case.

Comment: I changed the example to show how it can be done using the focus event for a specific (dynamically created) div instead of click.